# How do i find the download link for the newest version of (asp).net core for raspbian?

Tags: .net-core, raspberry-pi

I know there's https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download for most Linux versions, but I wasn't able to get any of them running on my Raspberry. I was lucky to find a blog with the direct link for wget.

I'm not asking for current links, I'm asking for how i can get the current stable version for future releases, or even better where i find links for every version available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the real download page: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0

You can find links to ".NET Core binaries" under the "Linux" section for each release on that page.

These are not stable links - each time there is a release, you will have to look and and find the link to the latest release (a new row in the table) manually.

You should use the "ARM64" or "ARM32" links depending on what your Raspberry Pi version is.

These binaries are "portable", meaning they should work irrespective of what distro you are using (as long as it's a recent-enough distro).